# Same Id, not same value if one not OK, exclude all with id

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

Hello I have two Tables in symfony join by ManyToOne bidirectional relationship.
articles and dates.

And in my table (dates) i have :

```
+----------------------------
| id   | a.id  | OK OR NOT ? 
+----------------------------
| 1    | 4     |      OK 
| 2    | 4     |      OK 
| 3    | 6     |      OK 
| 4    | 5     |      OK 
| 5    | 4     |   **NOTOK** 
----------------------------

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
           ->select('a')
           ->leftJoin('a.dates','d')
           ->where('CONDITION OK OR NOT') 
           ->orderBy('a.id', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

How can I have in result ALL the articles except a.id : 4 because one of them doesn't respond to the condition ???

Comment: Is the join supposed to be from "a.dates" to "d"? Or maybe that should instead be "a.dates = d.dates"?

Comment: Yes, the join is from a (articles) to d (dates)

Answer (score 0):

You should use ->notIn() :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
   ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('a.id','SELECT a.id FROM AppBundle:Articles LEFT JOIN a.dates d WHERE d.OK_OR_NOT = "**NOTOK**"'))
   ->orderBy('a.id', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.Expr.html#427-444